# angular2-busy not showing animations - Angular 4

Tags: css, angular, angular-animations

I'm using `angular2-busy` with an Angular 4 project. When I use the `ngBusy` directive I only get the default message, no animation including a backdrop. I am importing the `busy.css` file in my `index.html` and imported both the `BusyModule` and `BroswerAnimationModule`.

Here is how I am using it:

```
 this.busy = this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => 
 this.httpService.getEventHistory(+params.get('site_no')))
.subscribe(events => {this.events = events});
```

I don't know whether this is related, but the "Please Wait" message stays on the screen even after the data has loaded.

Edit: I moved the CSS link from the `index.html` file into the `.angular-cli.json` file under `styles`. I am still facing the same issue.

Here is the package I am trying to use: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-busy

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are doing and I haven't used this library before, but my guess is the `this.route` part is causing a problem. Try displaying a busy indicator for a more basic subscription.

Comment: I tried it on a basic subscription, and I don't have the hanging issue, but it is still not showing any animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just manually copying the styles into my global `styles.css` file. Not ideal, but it works.